# How to correctly unparse python functions docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, docstring

I have this simple docstring parser example that prints the code string of a function:

```
import ast
import astunparse

class AnalysisNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, nodename):
        super().__init__()
        self.nodename=nodename
        self.setVariables={}
    def visit_FunctionDef(self,node):
        for thing in node.body:
            if isinstance(thing, ast.Expr):
                print(astunparse.unparse(thing))
        

        
Analyzer=AnalysisNodeVisitor("example1")
tree=ast.parse('''\
def add(a,b):  
    """
    this adds two numbers
    """
    return a+b
''')
Analyzer.visit(tree)
```

for this example the output is like so :

[image]

```
'\n    this adds two numbers\n    '
```

which is what I don't understand, is there a way to print(or rather parse then unparse) the docstring the way it is:

```
"""
    this adds two numbers
"""
```

This is just an example to showcase my question, in my real example i tried to transform a python file (using nodetrasnformer class from ast module) and write a copy from it after certain trasnformations and all my docstrings were transformed that way, I also used astunparse.unparse method too just like in this example.

Comment: All of the various forms of string literals produce exactly the same kind of string object.  The AST *intentionally* throws away such details, so that later stages of the compilation do not have to care about them.

Comment: So, is there no other choice but to remove my docstring nodes and ignore them in the copied files?